# Function to Open Arbitrary Program from WSL terminal

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having trouble writing a program that takes the `/path/to/file` in an WSL Ubuntu environment and opens that file in its default Windows program. The biggest issue here is converting the `/path/to/file/for/WSL` into a `path\to\file\for\windows`. This is what I wrote and put in my `.bashrc` file:

```
# Function to get open-wsl to work  
  function open-from-wsl() {  
          echo "opening"  
          cmd_directory = echo "$1" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/^...../\0C:/' | sed 's/^\mnt//'  
          cmd_directory = echo "$cmd_directory" | sed 's/^..//'  
          cmd.exe /C start $cmd_directory  
  }
```

Ideally what this is supposed to accomplish is if I type :

```
open-from-wsl /mnt/c/Users/DavidG/Google\ Drive/folder/file.PDF
```

I'll have my `file.PDF` open in my default PDF viewer. As of right now however, I get the error `cmd_directory: command not found` and then my command prompt window opens up. This of course is being written so that I can open any file from WSL and have it open in it's default program, it doesn't just pertain to PDFs.

EDIT: I've adjusted the code like so thanks to Socowi's input:

```
# Function to get open-wsl to work  
  function open-from-wsl() {  
          echo "opening"
          cmd_directory=$(echo "$1" | sed 's#\##')  
          cmd_directory=$(echo "$cmd_directory" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/^...../\0C:/' | sed 's/^\mnt//')  
          cmd_directory=$(echo "$cmd_directory" | sed 's/^..//')  
          cmd.exe /C start $cmd_directory  
  }
```

My issue now seems to be that I can't remove the `\` from `/mnt/c/Users/DavidG/Google\ Drive/folder/file.PDF`, which was my goal by adding the line

```
cmd_directory=$(echo "$1" | sed 's#\##')
```

Comment: Remove the spaces around `=` and encapsulate `echo ... | sed ... | ...` in `$()`.

Comment: I was under the impression that wslpath only took Windows paths and converted them to a Ubuntu path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching among various questions pertaining to adjacent-esque issues. I finally found the solution. This is the function that I ended up putting into my `.bashrc` file:

```
# Function to get open an arbitrary file in its default Windows program
function open-from-wsl() {
     echo "opening"
     cmd_directory=$(echo "$1" | sed 's#[\]##')
     cmd_directory=$(echo "$cmd_directory" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/^...../\0C:/' | sed 's/^\mnt//')
     cmd_directory=$(echo "$cmd_directory" | sed 's/^..//')
     echo "$cmd_directory"
     cmd.exe /C start ""  "$cmd_directory"
}
```

This will allow you to open any file in your computer (assuming you know the WSL path to it) in it's default Windows program.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution is to create a file in /usr/bin/ called v (v for view, i like short commands, but you can call it anything you like) containing the following:

```
cmd.exe /C start $(wslpath -w "$(pwd)/$1")
```

Now assuming /usr/bin is in the wsl path just call `v foo.txt` to open a file in its default windows editor.

[wslpath](https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath) is used to convert the wsl path to a dos path. This is now included in the wsl install ([link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/releases/tag/17046))